# Lightning Tree grid not Expanding for Self parent Scenario

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to create a hierarchy like structure for my custom object Project which have a custom field called Parent_Project__c. I am facing an issue where the data is returning correctly in JS array. but it is not getting expanded on Screen.

following is the LWC code.

html code

```
<template>
   <lightning-card title="Project Hierarchy">
    <lightning-tree-grid
    columns={columns}
    data={projects}
    key-field="Name"
    expanded-rows={expandedRows}
    onrowsexpand={handleRowExpand}
    onrowcollapse={handleRowCollapse}
    >
    </lightning-tree-grid>
</lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS code

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getProjects from '@salesforce/apex/ProjectController.getProjects';

export default class HierarchyProject extends LightningElement {
    @track projects= []
    @wire(getProjects)
    wiredProjects({data, error}){
        if(data){
            console.log(data)
            const projects = this.convertToTreeData(data)
            this.projects = projects
            //this.projects = data
        }
        if(error){
            console.error(error)
        }
    }

    @track columns = [
        { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text' }]

        @track expandedRows = new Set();

        convertToTreeData(projects){
            let treeGridData = []
            let projectMap = []

            projects.forEach(project => {
                projectMap[project.Id] = {
                    Id : project.Id,
                    Name : project.Name,
                    Parent_Project__c : project.Parent_Project__c,
                    children:[]
                };
            });
            console.log(projects)

            projects.forEach(project => {
                if (project.Parent_Project__c) {
                    const parentId = project.Parent_Project__c;
                    projectMap[parentId].children.push(projectMap[project.Id]);
                } else {
                    if (!projectMap[project.Id].Parent_Project__c) {
                        treeGridData.push(projectMap[project.Id]);
                    }
                    //treeGridData.push(projectMap[project.Id]);
                }
            });
            console.log(treeGridData)

            return treeGridData;
        }

        handleRowExpand(event) {
            this.expandedRows.add(event.detail.rowKey);
        }

        handleRowCollapse(event) {
            this.expandedRows.delete(event.detail.rowKey);
        }
}
```

The first master element does not have any parent project. is that the issue. Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

`children` should be `_children`.

Also, note your code is entirely too complicated, you could have just written something like:

```
const projectMap = Object.fromEntries(
  projects.map((project) => [
    project.Id,
    {
      ...project,
      Parent_Project__c: project.Parent_Project__c || "",
      _children: [],
    },
  ])
);
projectMap[""] = { _children: [] }; // This is the "root" node for projects without parents
Object.values(projectMap).forEach((project) =>
  projectMap[project.Parent_Project__c]._children.push(project)
);
```

Comment: I tried this. it didn't worked